# Magento different page for same category for mutiple store

Tags: magento

I have two stores using same root category. I have a category 'Clothing'. I would like to show a static block for Store 1 for 'Clothing' category. And I would like to show 'products only' for category 'Clothing' in Store 2. Is this possible? Or do you have an alternative for such a requirement? Basically we move out dated products from store 1 to store 2. So products in Store 1 and Store 2 will be different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `Display Mode` for a category has the scope `Store view`. This means you can set for example 'Products only' on the default settings, then change the scope to the first store view and set it's value 'Statick block'.